# custom questions in SQL database, wondering how to get users answers foreach questions

Tags: php

Sorry for the question - it might not make sense, it's a bit hard to explain.

I currently have a table in my database called `customquestions`.

The table looks like this

[image: CustomQuestionsTable]

On my front end i have the following code which displays questions based on the column 'opportunity_id'. So when the user is on the page for the opportunity with the ID '12' it displays the questions from the database, along with a text box for an answer.

```
 $questions = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM (`applicationquestions`)
            WHERE opportunity_id = $opporunityinfo->id
        ");

        $questions = $questions->result(); ?>

<textarea name = "coverletter" id ="coverletter"> </textarea>


<? foreach ($question as $q):?>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="<?echo $q->id;?>" class="control-label"><? echo $q->label;? 
>:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?echo $q->id;?>">
</div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is when a user puts in their answer and submits it, it then gets the text from the coverletter box and also the answers for each question, but then puts it in a column in another table with a column called "cover letter".

For example it would end up putting the cover letter and the questions and answers in one body of text.

Coverletter

"Hi my name is john blah blah 
 Have you ever sold web design before? 
 Yes "

My insert code =

```
    $coverletter = $this->input->post('coverletter') . "<br><br>"; 

// need to put questions & answers here automatically and then join it to $coverletter

 $insert['opportunity_id']= $this->input->post('oppid');

         $insert['user_id']= is_user_logged_in();
 $insert['time']= time();
 $insert['coverletter']= $coverletter;
         $this->db->insert("applications", $insert);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you will need to necessarily worry about getting the text from the body to put into the database, I would personally store the answer in another table, but referencing the original questions.

So the table could be: (id, answer, userid, opportunityid) values (1, 'Yes i have', '1', '12'); or something like that

You could then pull the values from the database after would and put it all together at the end.

The benefit of this is that you are storing less information in your database, so the database will not be as big (less data duplication)

Once all of the questions have been answered then you can write a script to put it all together. Or even have a function to put what has been completed together as you go.

Does that make sense? I would be happy to provide more clarification.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. i think I have been over thinking it a lot, and that is the best solution, something I should of though of at first. Thank you!

Comment: I have created the table e.t.c, but now unsure on how to insert the answers to the questions into the new table. Any ideas?

Comment: How are you pulling the data from the form? Are you submitting the form using post? If so `$_POST['formItemName'];` would be the syntax to use to retrieve the answers that the user posted in the form. You then just pass that info back to the database

Comment: using jscript / ajax -  $.ajax({
             url: "https://XXXX.com/apicalls/submitapplication",
             method: "POST",
             data: {oppid:oppid},

Comment: the issue is, each question gives the textbox the id for that question, if that makes sense

Comment: I have created another question so that its easier to understand, thanks for ur help so far

Comment: If the form only contains questions and nothing else, you can pass it all back as an array, and then just loop through the array to add it to the database